# How does Java compare Sets?

Tags: java, set, comparison

I have a class

```
class Foo
{
   int x;
   Set<Integer> set;
}
```

When I build a set `Set<Foo>`, it compiles and runs. Comparing integers are simple, but how does Java compare two sets?

Should I override as

```
        if(this.toBeLocalized != that.toBeLocalized)
        {
            if(this.set.size() == that.set.size())
            {
                Set<Integer> ref = new HashSet<>();
                ref.addAll(this.set);
                ref.removeAll(that.set);
                if(ref == null)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Or there is a comparison for sets?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Beware with the vocable "compare"... Some developers might understand `Comparable` which is not quite the same thing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is implementation of methd equals from class `AbstractSet`, and most of implementations of `Set` will extends it

```
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;

    if (!(o instanceof Set))
        return false;
    Collection c = (Collection) o;
    if (c.size() != size())
        return false;
        try {
            return containsAll(c);
        } catch (ClassCastException unused)   {
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Set` already defines `.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), and all implementations of `Set` are required to implement it the way the doc says (and, of course, it goes for `.hashCode()` as well).

So you just have to:

```
set1.equals(set2)
```

Note that the contract stipulate that *order of elements does not matter*, so `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 1, 3]` are equal. This is unlike `List` where order *does* matter.